# adding a value to my combo box using query

Tags: vb.net, vba

I'm trying to populate my combo box using the information in my database.. but I don't know the code for populating it. btw, I'm using vb windows form.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=PC11-PC\kim;Initial Catalog=Acounting;User ID=sa;Password=123")
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("select distinct CompanyName from company ", con)
    cmd.ExecuteReader()
    con.Open()
    While cmd.ExecuteReader.Read
    End While
    con.Close()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, _
    ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Using cnn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=PC11-PC\kim;Initial Catalog=Acounting;User ID=sa;Password=123")
        Using Adp as new SqlDataAdapter("select distinct CompanyName from company", con)
            Dim Dt as New DataTable
            Adp.Fill(Dt)
            ComboBox1.DataSource=Dt
            ComboBox1.DisplayMember="CompanyName"
        End Using 
        End Using 
End Sub
```

Comment: it's still not populating the combobox sir.

Comment: you need to load the data in `Form1_Load` event, not in `ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged`

Comment: I get it sir. so when I run the system it'll automatically populate the combo box. thanks sir.. you're a great help.

Answer (score 0):

```
  Using cnn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=PC11-PC\kim;Initial Catalog=Acounting;User ID=sa;Password=123")
    Using cmd As New SqlCommand("select distinct CompanyName from company", cnn)

    Try
      cnn.Open()
      Dim r = cmd.ExecuteReader

      If r.HasRows Then
        While r.Read
          ''add the items to the ComboBox
          ComboBox1.Items.Add(r.GetString(0))
        End While
      End If
    Catch ex As Exception
      ''handle the error
    End Try
  End Using
End Using
```

Comment: it's still not populating sir. I'm new to vb so bear with me sir. =) in this line of code "ComboBox1.Items.Add(r.GetString(0))" what should I put there? or it'll automatically fill in the combo box?

Comment: You need to be more specific. Does it throw an exception? Are you able to get data back from the database? What happens when you use the debugger and step through one line at a time?

Comment: I actually have the information in my databasetable "Company" and I want the "CompanyName" to display in the dropdownlist.

Comment: I already get it sir. thanks. my bad, I should put the code on the form_load.. thanks for the help. Appreciate it! =)